# Gegenteil von Rücktritt (am Fahrrad)

Tags: single-word-request

Neulich hatte ich eine Diskussion über das Wort *Rücktritt* im Kontext von Fahrrädern. Die Frage war, ob *mit Rücktritt* besagt, dass man beim Rückwärtstreten bremst oder genau **nicht** bremst. Nach einer Google-Suche war klar, dass es normalerweise bedeutet, dass man bremst.

Und da kam die folgende Frage auf:  Gibt es eigentlich auch eine „offizielle“ Bezeichnung dafür, wenn man nach hinten durchtreten kann, ohne dass was passiert?

> Mein Fahrrad hat ____ .

Comment: Ach so, und _Rücktritt_ ist eine Verkürzung von _Rücktrittbremse_. Erst wenn das jemandem nicht mehr bewußt ist, kann es zu Unsicherheit über die Bedeutung kommen.

Comment: IMO könnte die Wortsuche schwierig werden, weil eine *Rücktrittbremse* ein extra Feature ist, das, wenn es nicht eingebaut ist, automatisch einen Freilauf zur Folge hat. Das Gegenteil wäre dann einfach nur *Fahrrad ohne Rücktrittbremse*: Bin gespannt auf die Antworten!

Comment: @Takkat... interessanterweise ist für mich ein Rücktritt der "Normalfall". Die Fahrräder mit denen ich in der Zone groß geworden bin, hatten alle Rücktritt :). Das Nach-Hinten-Durchdrehen war für mich auf jeden Fall neu und cool und techy.

Comment: Selbst das uralte Miele-Fahrrad meiner Mutter hatte schon eine. Hier ein interessanter Link zur Geschichte der Sachs-Nabe mit Rücktritt: http://fahrradzukunft.de/17/fichtel-und-sachs-geschichte/

Comment: Ja, auch im Westen (und in Holland und Skandinavien) hatten Rücktrittnaben früher fast ein Monopol. Manche Leute trauen sich heute noch nicht auf ein Fahrrad mit moderner Schaltung. Anderswo ist die Rücktrittbremse kaum bekannt.

Comment: @Emanuel Mein Vater hatte ein Diamantsportrad - mit Freilauf. Und auch in der _Zone_ gab es (wenn man genügend Ladentische abgeklappert hat oder mal zum Einkaufen bei den Tschechen war) Kettengangschaltungen. Meist mit 3 (drei), manchmal mit 4 oder 5 Gängen. Solche Räder hatten natürlich auch immer einen Freilauf. - Von daher war es für mich schon immer ein entweder/oder, aber keine Variante ein Normalfall. Erst in jüngerer Zeit - bin schon ewig nicht mehr mit Rücktritt gefahren,

Comment: @Emanuel: Von mir sind sie nicht, aber "Mein Fahrrad hat ..." würde ich nicht mit "Rücktritt" fortsetzen; schon weil meines einen Leerlauf hat, - nein - die Verkürzung ist arg. "Mein Fahrrad hat Mumms". "Ich bremse mit Rücktritt" geht. "Mein Fahrrad hat eine Klingel". Dagegen "Mein Fahrrad hat Klingel".

Comment: "Kettenschaltung"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Frage ist eher technischer Natur. Ein Fahrrad ohne Rücktritt(bremse) hat entweder einen starren Gang oder einen Freilauf.

Ein starrer Gang (auch Fixie oder Fixed Gear genannt, auch im Deutschen) bedeutet, dass die Pedale direkt auf das Hinterrad übersetzt sind. Wenn sich die Pedale drehen, dreht sich das Hinterrad; bleiben die Pedale stehen, bleibt auch das Hinterrad stehen. Das Gleiche gilt auch umgekehrt: Dreht sich das Hinterrad, drehen sich auch die Pedale.

Ein Freilauf bedeutet, dass die Pedale stehen bleiben können oder sich rückwärts drehen können, auch wenn das Hinterrad sich dreht.

Comment: +1 Ich kenne _mit Freilauf_ als Gegenteil von _mit Rücktritt_ seit meiner Kindheit. Aber hast Du vielleicht noch eine Referenz dafür?

Comment: +1 für Freilauf, auch wenn das Wort alleine meiner Meinung nach nicht genügt, da man es so verstehen kann, dass das Rad keine starre Nabe hat, was eine Rücktrittsbremse noch nicht ausschließt.

Comment: Das ist tatsächlich richtig. Freilauf ist das Gegenteil von starrer Nabe. Freilauf und Rücktritt schließen sich nicht aus (im Gegenteil). Keinen Rücktritt zu haben bedeutet aber, dass man entweder eine starre Nabe oder einen Freilauf (ohne Rücktritt) hat.

Answer (score 9):

Rücktritt ist die Abkürzung für Rücktrittbremse.
Daher gibt der Satz „Mein Fahrrad hat Rücktritt“ an, welche Art von Bremsen an deinem Rad verbaut ist.
Wenn du also keine Rücktrittbremse hast, wäre es korrekt, auf dein Bremssystem hinzuweisen. Zum Beispiel mit:

> Mein Fahrrad hat Felgenbremsen.

oder

> Mein Fahrrad hat Scheibenbremsen.

Im Sprachgebrauch ist es allerdings unüblich, auf Felgenbremsen oder Scheibenbremsen hinzuweisen. Deshalb würden wohl die meisten einfach sagen:

> Mein Fahrrad hat keinen Rücktritt.

---

Es gibt aber auch noch weitere Varianten, wie das Hinterrad gebremst (oder auch nicht gebremst) werden kann.
So besitzen die meisten Räder einen Freilauf, was bedeutet, dass sich das Rad weiterdreht, auch wenn man nicht in die Pedale tritt. Manche Räder, wie zum Beispiel Singlespeed (oder auch Fixie genannt), haben keinen Freilauf und keine Hinterradbremse. Diese werden gebremst, indem man den Pedalen entgegendrückt und somit Pedale, Kette und damit auch Hinterrad abbremst.
In diesem Fall würde man sagen

> „Mein Fahrrad hat eine starre Nabe“ oder „Mein Fahrrad wird über die starre Nabe gebremst“

Und schließlich gibt es noch Fahrräder mit Freilauf und keiner Hinterradbremse. Hier würde man wahrscheinlich einfach sagen, dass man keine Bremsen hat.

---

Zusammenfassend lässt sich sagen, das Gegenteil von Rücktritt ist kein Rücktritt. Besser ist es aber zu sagen, was für ein Bremssystem man anstelle von Rücktritt hat.

Comment: Wobei eine andere Bremse, selbst am Hinterrad, das Vorhandensein einer Rücktrittbremse nicht ausschließt. Viele Räder mit Rücktrittbremse haben zusätzlich Felgenbremsen vorne und hinten.

Answer (score 4):

Es scheint keinen speziellen Begriff dafür zu geben. Ich würde sagen:

> Hat dieses Fahrrad eine Rücktrittbremse? – Nein, das ist ein Rad ohne Rücktrittbremse.

Wenn man unbedingt eine positive Bezeichnung will, könnte man von *Freilauf* sprechen: *Mein Fahrrad hat einen Freilauf.* Das wäre aber mehrdeutig, weil auch Räder mit Rücktrittbremse einen Freilauf in einer Richtung haben (die Kette wird nicht mitbewegt, wenn sich das Hinterrad dreht). Zur Verdeutlichung könnte man vielleicht *Rückwärts-Freilauf* bilden.

Comment: _Rückwärts-Freilauf_ wäre doppelt gemoppelt. Der (Fach-)Begriff schließt die einseitige Wirkung schon mit ein, siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freilauf_%28Mechanik%29

Comment: @Matthias: Ich hänge nicht an dem Begriff, aber wie ich schon schrieb, genügt nur _Freilauf_ nicht zur Beschreibung, da Rücktrittbremsnaben ebenfalls einen Freilauf haben: Wenn das Fahrrad rollt, kannst du „leer“ oder gar nicht treten, und das Hinterrad rotiert unbeeinflußt weiter. Siehe zum Beispiel [Torpedo-Freilaufnabe auf Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torpedo-Freilaufnabe): _Hinterradnabe mit und ohne Gangschaltung für Fahrräder mit Freilauf und Rücktrittbremse._

Answer (score -1):

In meiner Umgebung war gebräuchlich: treten

Und ich halte es für das Gegenteil von (zu)rücktreten. Auf dem Fahrrad:

Tritt, um vorwärts zu kommen!
Halt! Tritt zurück man!

Um unterscheiden zu können sagten wir.

Mein Fahrrad hat Rücktritt. (Ich konnte bremsen wenn ich zurück tritt.)

Dein Fahrrad hat Rücklauf. (Du trittst zurück im Leerlauf.)

Comment: Und wie bezieht sich das jetzt auf die Frage? „Mein Fahrrad hat Tritt“? Scheint mir nicht verständlich zu sein.

Comment: Tritt und Rücktritt sind gegensätzlich. Mit Rücktritt kann auch bremsen gemeint sein.

Comment: @chirlu Ich glaube ich weiß was Du meinst. Ich sollte ja den letzten Satz vervollständigen. Ist mir entfallen. Ist spät in Kuala Lumpur :-(